# VirtualBox Xubuntu: Can't view Internet videos, No sound on VLC, Parole is dead

Tags: sound, virtualbox, xubuntu, video, vlc

I recently installed a Virtual 16.04 Xubuntu system on my Windows 10 Laptop using VirtualBox for the sole use of learning Web Dev. Everything's going swimmingly, but I can't get videos to work.

No matter what site I visit, all the videos load half a second then buffer indefinitely, the video bar loads fully but the video never resumes. I use Firefox but the same problem occurs in Chromium. I get the same problem with `.webm` files too.

With VLC, I get a little progress. The video plays, but I get no audio. When I tried the same video with Parole, I get a `gstreamer back-end error`

I've scoured the internet for hours and I've tried everything. `sudo apt-get install restricted-ubuntu-extras`, Re-installed Flash Player, Checked Youtube/html5 (all's well), Installed Guest Additions, even did the tried and true Fresh Install. Incidentally, when the installation finished I went straight onto Youtube and found that nothing had changed.

I supposed I'm grateful because I'm now a bit more comfortable with the Linux Terminal, but nothing seems to work. Any Suggestions? or am I going to have to run whatever videos I need through a window in my ...uhh... Windows?